# "Protractor Test scripts" are not running , displaying "Type script" compilation error messages

Tags: typescript, jasmine, protractor

Recently i installed "ParamMap" package to use this module in my code.

For that i run below command

```
npm install @angular/common@latest @angular/compiler@latest @angular/compiler-cli@latest @angular/core@latest @angular/forms@latest @angular/http@latest @angular/platform-browser@latest @angular/platform-browser-dynamic@latest @angular/platform-server@latest @angular/router@latest @angular/animations@latest typescript@latest --save
```

after installation of "paramMap" , when i run my e2e folder

```
C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app>ng e2e
```

it is displaying below error

```
[16:41:41] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
[16:41:41] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[16:41:44] E/launcher - Error: TSError: ⨯ Unable to compile TypeScript
Cannot find type definition file for 'jasmine'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'node'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'q'. (2688)
Cannot find type definition file for 'selenium-webdriver'. (2688)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (2,38): Cannot find module 'protractor'. (2307)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (3,11): Cannot find name 'require'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (5,1): Cannot find name 'describe'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (9,3): Cannot find name 'beforeEach'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (14,3): Cannot find name 'afterEach'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (19,3): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (21,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (25,3): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (28,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (33,3): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (36,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (40,3): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (42,5): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (47,3): Cannot find name 'it'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (56,9): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (63,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (66,7): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (71,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (82,9): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (90,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (96,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (105,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (109,7): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (112,7): Cannot find name 'expect'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (124,5): Cannot find name 'xit'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (135,22): Cannot find name 'Buffer'. (2304)
e2e\app.e2e-spec.ts (139,4): Cannot find name 'it'. (2304)
    at getOutput (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:258:17)
    at C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:267:16
    at Object.compile (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:403:17)
    at loader (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:289:33)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .ts] (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts:306:14)
    at Module.load (C:\Users\agudla\node_modules\coffee-script\lib\coffee-script\register.js:45:36)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:71:5
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Jasmine.loadSpecs (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:70:18)
    at Jasmine.execute (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\jasmine\lib\jasmine.js:154:8)
    at C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:129:15
    at Function.promise (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:682:9)
    at C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\built\frameworks\jasmine.js:101:14
    at _fulfilled (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:834:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:863:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:796:13)
    at C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:556:49
    at runSingle (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:137:13)
    at flush (C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\q\q.js:125:13)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
[16:41:44] E/launcher - Process exited with error code 100


npm ERR! Windows_NT 10.0.15063
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "e2e" "--" "./protractor.conf.js"
npm ERR! node v6.11.3
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! my-app@0.0.0 e2e: `protractor "./protractor.conf.js"`
npm ERR! Exit status 100
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the my-app@0.0.0 e2e script 'protractor "./protractor.conf.js"'.
npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the my-app package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     protractor "./protractor.conf.js"
npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
npm ERR!     npm bugs my-app
npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls my-app
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\agudla\Desktop\Vasundhara\VSCodeWorkspce6\my-app\npm-debug.log

Some end-to-end tests failed, see above.

Can anyone help me how to solve the "Type script" issue.
```

Comment: can you provide your `protractor.conf.js`? It looks like `jasmine` is not installed or cannot be found by protractor. Maybe you also want to try it with `jasmine2` rather than `jasmine`.

Comment: @ErnstZwingli thanks for your reply.Below is the "Protractor.conf.js" file code var SpecReporter = require('jasmine-spec-reporter');
exports.config = {
   specs: [ './e2e/**/*.e2e-spec.ts'],
  capabilities: { 'browserName': 'chrome'},
  directConnect: true,
  baseUrl: 'http://localhost:4200/',framework: 'jasmine', jasmineNodeOpts: { showColors: true,defaultTimeoutInterval: 30000,print: function() {}},
  useAllAngular2AppRoots: true, beforeLaunch: function() {require('ts-node').register({project: 'e2e'});},onPrepare: function() {jasmine.getEnv().addReporter(new SpecReporter()); }};

Comment: I added the config-file as an Edit-suggestion to the question. As I can't find anything to stick out of the config-file, I don't really see, where it comes from. So I'd suggest to just do a Jasmine-Update - [see npm-jasmine-site](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jasmine). Also check your `my-app\node_modules\ts-node\src\index.ts`, how it got changed by your `ParamMap` installation... maybe the jasmine part got overwritten. Other than that I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You can obtain the type information using NPM in the same way that you install the dependencies, the only difference is that you save it as a development dependency, and obtain it from the `@types` organisation.

For example, the type definitions for Angular can be obtained using:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/angular
```

You can search for the packages using the [Definitely Typed package search](https://microsoft.github.io/TypeSearch/).